# Android application based on single activity, multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

In iOS I may write an entire application using a single UIViewController and simply adding the entire application within a UIView hierarchy. This works ok as the UIViewController gets a notification when the memory situation is bad and lets the developer do some manual memory management/optimization.

Is there an equivalent to this in Android? 
Could I write an entire application in a single activity and stack fragments on top of this?
What implications would this have on memory usage as as far as I understand, this of circumvents the activity lifecycle management and the entire stack of fragments would remain in memory - or am I wrong?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there an equivalent to this in Android?

Not from a memory-management standpoint. You are not explicitly told of low heap space. Use of things like `SoftReference` can help, but that's more at the virtual machine level.

> Could I write an entire application in a single activity and stack fragments on top of this?

If you wanted to, yes.

> What implications would this have on memory usage as as far as I understand, this of circumvents the activity lifecycle management and the entire stack of fragments would remain in memory - or am I wrong?

The "entire stack of fragments" would be in memory regardless of whether they are hosted by 1 activity or N activities.

Comment: If they are hosted by N activities, then they would be part of the activity's lifecycle management. If they are all in a single view doesn't this mean that the single activity is always in memory with all its fragments as it is the only visible

Comment: @user204884: Activities only leave memory if either you manually `finish()` them, or if the user presses BACK (and you allow normal BACK button processing), or the process is terminated. Hence, by default, having 1 activity vs. having N activities can have the same memory footprint with respect to fragments. Having N activities *can* have lower memory footprint, but it is not guaranteed. My apologies for not making that clearer in my answer.

Comment: @CommonsWare I accept your answer but how to remove all fragments at time along with Activity holding them to clear memory. Will it clear memory immediately or else take some time.